# Rendering words within text that is commented out in R chunk possible?

Tags: r, r-markdown, backticks

In a Rmarkdown document and outside a chunk, a word within backticks, for example *text*, will show as `text` in the corresponding rendered document. Is there a way to do the same with words within a text that is commented out inside an R chunk? For example, if i have inside a chunk

```
# This text is not evaluated
```

Is it possible to have the word *text* in the above line rendered in the same way it would when it is outside the R chunk and within backticks?

Thanks!